# jq error when using if then else with scan

Tags: jq

I have json:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "projectcalico.org/v3",
  "kind": "NetworkPolicy",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "allow-tcp-6379",
    "namespace": "production"
  },
  "spec": {
    "selector": "all()",
...
}
```

I select the fields I need with the command `jq 'if .spec.selector == "all()" then "{}" else (scan("([0-9A-Za-z_]+) == '([0-9A-Za-z_]+)") | {(.[0]): .[1]}) end | {selector: .}'`

But if I change the field to `.spec.selector: "app =='nginx'"` then I get an error - `jq: error (at <stdin>:39): object ({"apiVersio...) cannot be matched, as it is not a string exit status 5`

How to fix this?

jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/7zS1CTHM69

Comment: Input to `scan` should be a string. You're passing your entire input (the object itself) in that context. What exactly are you matching against?

Comment: Your sample command `jq '… scan("… ' …") …'` has a single quote inside a jq string while the whole jq filter itself also uses single quotes as delimiters. This will break as the inner single quote will be interpreted as the end of the quoted part of the filter. You may want to enclose the literal single quote within double quotes and interrupt the single-quoted filter for this part: `jq '… scan("… '"'"' …") …'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying `scan` to the wrong thing.

```
if .spec.selector == "all()" then
   "{}"
else
   .spec.selector | 
   scan("([0-9A-Za-z_]+) == '([0-9A-Za-z_]+)") |
   { (.[0]): .[1] }
end
```

This simplifies to

```
.spec.selector |
if . == "all()" then
   "{}"
else
   scan("([0-9A-Za-z_]+) == '([0-9A-Za-z_]+)") |
   { (.[0]): .[1] }
end
```

It seems weird that you output a string in one path and an object in the other. Is this correct?

In addition to not specifying what you want from the three alternatives (`all()`, `x == 'y'`, other), you did not specify what output from the overall program, so it's not clear how this should be incorporated into your program.